# How do I plot percentile graph with interval data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

How do I plot percentile graph with interval data?

See the code below to calculate percentiles of data based on specific intervals.

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([39.9, 42.9,45.9,48.9,51.9,54.9,57.9])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bin": idx, "Frequency": [2,2,5,5,12,3]})
n = df["Frequency"].sum()
df['cumulativeSumFreq'] = df["Frequency"].cumsum()
df['cumulativePercent'] = (df["Frequency"]/n)*100
df

bins = [39.9, 42.9,45.9,48.9,51.9,54.9,57.9]
df.hist(column='cumulativePercent', bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

For some reason df.hist() does not except bins=idx

I get the following plot below which does not follow the correct binning. How would I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added the df. It would be Bins on the x axis and cumulative percent on the y axis

Comment: since it's a bar chart rather than a histogram your current suggestion doesn't come out as continuous interval data on the x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pyplot.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) or [`Axes.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stairs.html):

```
edges = [39.9, 42.9,45.9,48.9,51.9,54.9,57.9]
plt.stairs(df['cumulativePercent'], edges, fill=True)
```

or

```
edges = [39.9, 42.9,45.9,48.9,51.9,54.9,57.9]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stairs(df['cumulativePercent'], edges, fill=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because the hist method tries to create its own bins from the data instead of strictly using the ones you've provided. Instead of using the hist method, you can use bar to plot the histogram for pre-binned data.
Here's updated full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the dataframe
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([39.9, 42.9,45.9,48.9,51.9,54.9,57.9])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bin": idx, "Frequency": [2,2,5,5,12,3]})
n = df["Frequency"].sum()

# Calculate cumulative sum and cumulative percent
df['cumulativeSumFreq'] = df["Frequency"].cumsum()
df['cumulativePercent'] = (df["Frequency"]/n)*100

# Plotting the histogram using bar
left_edges = [interval.left for interval in df["Bin"]]
right_edges = [interval.right for interval in df["Bin"]]

# The bar heights will be the 'cumulativePercent' values
heights = df['cumulativePercent']

# Plot the bars
plt.bar(left_edges, heights, width=[right-left for left, right in zip(left_edges, right_edges)], align='edge', edgecolor='black')

# Label the x-axis
plt.xticks((left_edges + right_edges)[:-1], labels=[str(interval) for interval in df["Bin"]], rotation=45, ha="right")

plt.show()
```